# How to kill specific HTA based on window title

Tags: vbscript, dos, title, hta, taskkill

I have an HTA file with the filepath: C:\Users\ME\Desktop\DataTable.hta which has a window title of **DataTable** as declared in its code using `<title>DataTable</title>`

I'm trying to close this specific HTA window using DOS, javascript or vbscript. however, when I try to use taskkill in the following fashion its doesn't close. It works fine for notepad and other windows, but not for HTAs.

I type this into dos:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq DataTable
```

and nothing happens. Yet if I use:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Notepad
```

it successfully closes notepad. Why won't it work for HTAs? Is there a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We presume that you are running a HTA with this name : **DataTable.hta**.

So,we can kill this HTA by its name using a vbscript like that :

```
Option Explicit
Call KillProcessbyName("DataTable.hta")
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub KillProcessbyName(FileName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WshShell,strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,objProcess
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        If InStr(UCase(objProcess.CommandLine),UCase(FileName)) > 0 Then
            If Err <> 0 Then
                MsgBox Err.Description,VbCritical,Err.Description
            Else
                objProcess.Terminate(0) 
            End if
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: This solution can be adapted to work for me. I really like how I don't have to use the full filepath but simply the file name + extension. Very dynamic and useful. Hackoo, you win! Thanks a lot.